# From CATransform3D to CGAffineTransform

Tags: core-animation, core-graphics

I'm using the following function to apply a pulse effect to a view

```
- (void)pulse {

    CATransform3D trasform = CATransform3DScale(self.layer.transform, 1.15, 1.15, 1);
    trasform = CATransform3DRotate(trasform, angle, 0, 0, 0);

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:trasform];
    animation.autoreverses = YES;
    animation.duration = 0.3;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.repeatCount = 2;
    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pulseAnimation"];

}
```

**I would like to obtain the same result using the CGAffineTransform self.transform instead of the CATransform3D self.layer.transform.** Is this possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you care if you were applying a CATransform3D to a layer vs. a CGAffineTransform to a view, if you're already getting the result you desire from the former?

Comment: because the initial value of self.layer.transform is different from self.transform, isn't it?

Comment: I mean, before coming to the pulse method I apply some Affine transformations to the view, but I don't touch the layer, so I guess the transform is the identity there

Comment: To my knowledge, transforms applied to a view are translated into appropriate CATransform3Ds for the underlying layer. This is easy to verify by applying a transformation to your view, then running the above animation (with your nonfunctional `CATransform3DRotate()` removed, of course). It should be based on the previous transform of the UIView.

Comment: Thanks, my code was a bit unclear and I was getting the wrong animation. Therefore I guessed that the two transforms (layer and view) were different, but I was clearly wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

It's possible convert a `CATransform3D` to a `CGAffineTransform`, but you will lose some capabilities. I found it useful to convert the aggregate transform of a layer and its ancestors into a `CGAffineTransform` so I could render it with Core Graphics. The constraints are:

- Your input will be treated as flat in the XY plane
- Your output will be treated as flat in the XY plane too
- Perspective / foreshortening from `.m34` will be neutralized

If that sounds OK for your purposes:

```
    // m13, m23, m33, m43 are not important since the destination is a flat XY plane.
    // m31, m32 are not important since they would multiply with z = 0.
    // m34 is zeroed here, so that neutralizes foreshortening. We can't avoid that.
    // m44 is implicitly 1 as CGAffineTransform's m33.
    CATransform3D fullTransform = <your 3D transform>
    CGAffineTransform affine = CGAffineTransformMake(fullTransform.m11, fullTransform.m12, fullTransform.m21, fullTransform.m22, fullTransform.m41, fullTransform.m42);
```

You will want to do all your work in 3D transforms first, say by concatenating from your superlayers, and then finally convert the aggregate `CATransform3D` to a `CGAffineTransform`. Given that layers are flat to begin with and render onto a flat target, I found this very suitable since my 3D rotations became 2D shears. I also found it acceptable to sacrifice foreshortening. There's no way around that because affine transforms have to preserve parallel lines.

To render a 3D-transformed layer using Core Graphics, for instance, you might concatenate the transforms (respecting anchor points!), then convert to affine, and finally:

```
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, affine);
    [layer renderInContext:context];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer.  Unfortunately, it's one of those functions which *should* be included in the Cocoa APIs but isn't because it's not a "complete" conversion (and never could be).

Comment: I am so happy I found this.  I've been searching for "3d to 2d matrix" for a week now and just found a bunch of mathematical gibberish.

Comment: How the hell did you figure this out? This is awesome! I bow to your math genius.

Answer (score 3):

Of course. If you do a search on CGAffineTransform in the Xcode docs, you'll find a chapter titled "CGAffineTransform Reference". In that chapter is a section called "Functions". It includes functions that are equivalent to CATransform3DScale (CGAffineTransformScale ) and CATransform3DRotate (CGAffineTransformRotate).

Note that your call to CATransform3DRotate doesn't really make sense. You need to rotate around an axis, and you're passing 0 for all 3 axes. Typcially you want to use CATransform3DRotate(trasform, angle, 0, 0, **1.0**) to rotate around the Z axis. To quote the docs:

> If the vector has zero length the behavior is undefined.

Comment: But the point (maybe not clear from my question) is how to have an equivalent of [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

Comment: You're really not being clear. I'm guessing from the fact that CGAffineTransform is used for views and CATransform3D is used for layers that you want to know how to do view-based animation that specifies a different timing function. For that you want to use the animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
 UIView class method. The options parameter includes values like UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut, UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear, etc. Just specify the option that you want, and then change the transform in the animations block.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **CATransform3DGetAffineTransform** to convert CATransform3d to CGAffineTransform.

```
let scaleTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale( 0.8, 0.8, 1)
imageview.transform = CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(scaleTransform)
```