# How to convert CATransform3DTranslate to CGAffineTransform so it can Mimic a Carousel View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, transform

My question pertains to how to mimic this Carousel view [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCOAyIU5s90&t=1601s) **only using a UIView not it's layer or a CALayer**, which means actually transforming the UIViews its self.

I found a stack overflow question that actually is able to convert a
 **CATransform3D into a CGAffineTransform**. That was written by some genius [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497397/from-catransform3d-to-cgaffinetransform) as an answer, but my problem is a little unique.

The animation you see below is using CALayer to create. I need to create this same animation but transforming the UIView instead of its layer.

**What it's Supposed to look like:**

[image]

**Code (Creates animation using Layers):**
This takes an image card which is a CALayer() with a image attached to it and transforms which places it in the Carousel of images.

*Note: turnCarousel() is also called when the user pans which moves / animates the Carousel.*

```
 let transformLayer = CATransformLayer()

 func turnCarousel() {
    guard let transformSubLayers = transformLayer.sublayers else {return}

    let segmentForImageCard = CGFloat(360 / transformSubLayers.count)

    var angleOffset = currentAngle

    for layer in transformSubLayers {
        var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        transform.m34 = -1 / 500

        transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, degreeToRadians(deg: angleOffset), 0, 1, 0)
        transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0, 0, 175)

        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0)

        layer.transform = transform

        angleOffset += segmentForImageCard
    }
}
```

---

**What It Currently Looks Like:**
[image]

So basically it's close, but it seems as though there is a scaling issue with the cards that are supposed to be seen as *in the front* and the cards that are *in the back* of the carousel.

Fo this what I did is use a UIImageView as the base view for the carousel and then added more UIImageViews as cards to it. So now we are trying do a transformation on a UIImageView/UIView

**Code:**

```
  var carouselTestView = UIImageView()

  func turnCarouselTestCarousel() {
    let segmentForImageCard = CGFloat(360 / carouselTestView.subviews.count)

    var angleOffset = currentAngleTestView

    for subview in carouselTestView.subviews {
        var transform2 = CATransform3DIdentity
        transform2.m34 = -1 / 500

        transform2 = CATransform3DRotate(transform2, degreeToRadians(deg: angleOffset), 0, 1, 0)
        transform2 = CATransform3DTranslate(transform2, 0, 0, 175)

        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0)

        // m13, m23, m33, m43 are not important since the destination is a flat XY plane.
        // m31, m32 are not important since they would multiply with z = 0.
        // m34 is zeroed here, so that neutralizes foreshortening. We can't avoid that.
        // m44 is implicitly 1 as CGAffineTransform's m33.
        let fullTransform: CATransform3D = transform2
        let affine = CGAffineTransform(a: fullTransform.m11, b: fullTransform.m12, c: fullTransform.m21, d: fullTransform.m22, tx: fullTransform.m41, ty: fullTransform.m42)

        subview.transform = affine

        angleOffset += segmentForImageCard
    }
}
```

---

the sub image that actually make up the Carousel are add with this function which simply goes through a for loop of image named 1...6 in my assets folder.

**Code:**

```
 func CreateCarousel() {

    carouselTestView.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height / 2.9)
    carouselTestView.center = CGPoint(self.view.frame.width * 0.5, self.view.frame.height * 0.5)
    carouselTestView.alpha = 1.0
    carouselTestView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    carouselTestView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.insertSubview(carouselTestView, at: 0)

    for i in 1 ... 6 {
        addImageCardTestCarousel(name: "\(i)")
    }

    // Set the carousel for the first time. So that now we can see it like an actual carousel animation
    turnCarouselTestCarousel()

    let panGestureRecognizerTestCarousel = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.performPanActionTestCarousel(recognizer:)))
    panGestureRecognizerTestCarousel.delegate = self
    carouselTestView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizerTestCarousel)
  }
```

---

The addImageCardTestCarousel function is here:

**Code:**

```
    func addImageCardTestCarousel(name: String) {

    let imageCardSize = CGSize(width: carouselTestView.frame.width / 2, height: carouselTestView.frame.height)
    let cardPanel = UIImageView()
    cardPanel.frame.size = CGSize(width: imageCardSize.width, height: imageCardSize.height)
    cardPanel.frame.origin = CGPoint(carouselTestView.frame.size.width / 2 - imageCardSize.width / 2 , carouselTestView.frame.size.height / 2 - imageCardSize.height / 2)
    guard let imageCardImage = UIImage(named: name) else {return}
    cardPanel.image = imageCardImage
    cardPanel.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    cardPanel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cardPanel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    cardPanel.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cardPanel.layer.cornerRadius = cardPanel.frame.height / 50
    carouselTestView.addSubview(cardPanel)
}
```

**Purpose:**

The purpose of this is that I want to build a UI that can take UIViews on the rotating cards you see, and a CALayer cannot add a UIView as a subview. It can only add the UIView's layer to its own Layer. So to solve this problem I need to actually achieve this animation with UIViews not CALayers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it the view that Appears to be behind the front most view are actually grabbing all the touch even if you touch a card right in the front the back card will prevent touches for the front card. So i made a function that can calculate. Which views are in the front. Than disable and enable touches for then. Its like when 2 cards get stacked on top of each other the card to the back will stop the card from the front from taking/userInteraction.

Code:

```
   func DetermineFrontViews(view subview: UIView, angle angleOffset: CGFloat) {

    let looped = Int(angleOffset / 360) // must round down to Int()
    let loopSubtractingReset = CGFloat(360 * looped) // multiply 360 how ever many times we have looped

    let finalangle = angleOffset - loopSubtractingReset

    if (finalangle >= -70 && finalangle <= 70) || (finalangle >= 290) || (finalangle <= -260) {

        print("In front of view")

        if subview.isUserInteractionEnabled == false {
            subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    } else {
        print("Back of view")
        if subview.isUserInteractionEnabled == true {
            subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

I added this to the turn function to see if it could keep track of the first card being either in the back of the carousel or the front.

```
    if subview.layer.name == "1" {
            DetermineFrontViews(view: subview, angle: angleOffset)
        }
```